# Rendering another partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails.I am referring 'Agile web development with rails'. Here they are rendering another partial '_line_item' from the partial '_cart' using the syntax:

```
<%= render(cart.line_items) %>
```

My question is why use `cart` and not `@cart`? What is the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because instance variable `@cart` will not be available in partial `_cart`. Its render line probably looks like this:

```
<%= render partial: 'cart', locals: {cart: @user.cart} %>
```

or

```
<%= render 'cart', :cart => @user.cart %>
```

Therefore, user's cart is available as local variable `cart`.

Comment: `<%= render 'cart', :cart => @user.cart %>`

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because as you said here you are using the partial cart, not the cart model you saved to your @cart variable. The difference being that the partial cart is a view and @cart could really be anything as it is a variable but most likely is the model of your cart object.

Answer (score 1):

`@cart` is (probably) a specific instance of the `cart` class, but you're rendering a partial that refers to the `cart` object.

Answer (score 1):

The usage depends on how the view or the partial is called.

You can either define instance variables like `@cart = current_account.cart` which is then available in all views, subsequent partials or helpers you are calling from your controller.

Or you can call `render :partial=>'cart_page', :locals => { cart: @account.cart }` which only passes the variable specifically to the partial named 'cart' (without the @ since it is not globally available)

Comment: @vars are not globals

Comment: Alright, @vars are only on instance scope, being available to everything called within that instance. All render operations of views or partials can still access this var. I just always seem to call them global because when working in the upper layers, they sure seem like such ;)